# jqGrid Group summary not showing total sum with paging

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid, paging, grouping

This is my first post in this forum, so please, be patient with me.

I need to set my summary to show the sum of all rows in my grid, even the rows that are inside other pages - the absolute sum of values.

I was searching for it, and I saw a lot of people with this problem, so I don't think it is a problem with my code. It sounds more like a design in the grouping mechanism itself, otherwise I don't know.

But, to be clear, I think I need to make a call to server side to get the sum from there, is this possible? If so, how should I do it with json?

I was thinking about using the formatter option, but then it is triggered line by line, and I don't think this is the idea because the sum will come entire in the first call.

Any suggestions?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `summaryType` function to display your sum. According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping&s%5B%5D=summarytype) for `summaryType`:

> The option can be defined as function. If defined we pass three parameters to it - the current value, the name and the record object. The function should return value. Note that this value will be used again for the group value until it changes.

For example, you could retrieve a `totalSumRecord` when the page is loaded - it would be a bad idea to make an AJAX call directly from the formatter - and then just display the appropriate value in the formatter:

```
function myCustomSummary(val, name, record) {
    return totalSumRecord[name];
}

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({ 
  ...
  colModel : [
     {..},
     {name:'myColumn',
      index:'myColumn', 
      width:80, 
      align:"right", 
      sorttype:'number',
      formatter:'number',
      summaryType:myCustomSummary},
     ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

---

**Update**

There is a bug in jqGrid 4.4 where functions are not allowed as a summary type. If this affects you, [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/1d0901313546326e64586f1d9cfe13f746117201) is the fix.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but the function call goes only throw the items in the current page, and not the ones in another page.

Comment: That's why i am thinking about going to a sum in the server side, but then wen i group up items, it should affect the amount of pages it self, because of course, there are less rows to show.

Comment: I belive that i will have to abandon the grouping with jqgrid and make my own grouping with Link in the server side.

Comment: Yes, but a custom summary function allows you to display anything. So when your page loads you could write an object to it with the total summary counts (by group or whatever you need). Then just have your custom function display the counts from that object instead of data from the grid. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand what you want to say :) the problem is that the amount of pages don't change, because of course, i am not doing a server grouping, it will only change wen i refresh the grid with JSON info and then the grid will know the new amount. There is no way to do this via client. Grouping and change the number of records is not something that jqGrid does :) thanks anyway :)

Comment: if the client gets the full amount of data and store, somewhere and then make the paging, ok, then it can make changes, but other wise while he trusts the paging made in server side, there is no way to make a grouping in client-side that changes the grid data amounts and page amounts too. This is why jqGrid groups and counts only the rows visible in the current page, because it's the ones he haves at the moment :)

Comment: Agreed, we are saying the same thing. I am not clear why this answer is not helpful but clearly it does not meet your requirements. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Oh don't be mad, i understood your suggestion i have even implented it my self before opening the subject, it was one of the possible ways i dig up in my research, but it's not really what a i want :) thank you verymutch for trying, i think the only way to answer my question is a new module of jqGrid or something like that ^^

Comment: Thanks Justin - this worked well for me.  Unfortunately it just stopped working after upgrading to 4.4.0 - when the line (in groupingRender) "if(this.st == 'avg') {" was changed to "if(this.st.toLowerCase() === 'avg') {".  I've reverted back to 4.3.1.

Comment: Hmm... I see, is this because `this.st` is a function, so `st.toLowerCase()` is not defined?

Comment: Yep.  I suppose changing the source locally for something like this is worth it to get the multi-level grouping.  I'll report a bug on the trirand support site.

Comment: I entered a bug in their issue tracking system: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/336

Comment: thanks.  Someone else posted a related issue on the trirand support site:  http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/problem-in-grouping-in-v4-4-0/

Comment: Tony just fixed this: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/1d0901313546326e64586f1d9cfe13f746117201 - In the meantime, if this is your only 4.4 issue, I suggest going back to 4.4 but patching it manually in your copy of jqGrid. Normally this is a bad idea but you know the issue is fixed in the next release so you will not break yourself when you upgrade to 4.5 (or whatever the next version is).

Comment: I'm glad that the topic is usefull to more people :) Oh and i am really afraid of upgraiding my code. My jqGrid is 4.3.3.